# Angular6: Filter a list elements that match a property

Tags: angular, list, filter, pipe

I want to filter the *dataSource* of my angular table by displaying only the ***items*** that have a certain **groupId** property.

**component.html**

```
 <mat-table [dataSource]="groupSource |  filter : currentGroupId"></mat-table>
```

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
// return items of a group
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(group: any[], currentGroupId: number): any[] { 

    return group.filter( item=> item.groupId = currentGroupId);

    }
}
```

**However, I get this error:**

> ERROR TypeError: group.filter is not a function
>       at FilterPipe.push../src/app/filter.pipe.ts.FilterPipe.transform (filter.pipe.ts:9)
>       at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:9949)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10518)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (BasketComponent.html:144)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10699)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in the equality check.It should be

```
 return group.filter( item=> item.groupId === currentGroupId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the filter method on an Array when the datasource you are providing is likely a MatTableDataSource instance which is NOT an array. In fact, MatTableDataSource has a filter property which is supposed to be a string.

However, you will want to use the filterPredicate function of MatTableDataSource.

[Read the documentation for the correct way to filter a Material data source.](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering)